# unserialized in Magento\Framework\Message\Collection error

Tags: magento-2.1, unserialize

I have a integration using Magento 2 and Wordpress. 
For a specific plugin, when it is enabled I get this error in admin and frontend

> Fatal error: Magento\Framework\Message\Manager::getMessages(): The
>   script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete
>   object. Please ensure that the class definition
>   "Magento\Framework\Message\Collection" of the object you are
>   trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or
>   provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in
>   /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Message/Manager.php on
>   line 116

The message suggests that I should provide a autoload function to `Manager.php`

Can someone tell me how should I do that? How can I create a module that override that file if path is my wordpress install?

In order to do that I wrote a module. I don't know why it is not working. So my Magento 2 module looks like this

[image: Magento2 Module]

Here is my code

**di.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Message\Collection">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Gabriela_MessOverride_Plugin_Magento_Framework_Message_Collection" sortOrder="10" type="Gabriela\MessOverride\Plugin\Magento\Framework\Message\Collection"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Collection.php**:

```
<?php
/**
 * Override GetMessage()
 * Copyright (C) 2017  
 * 
 * This file is part of Gabriela/MessOverride.
 * 
 * Gabriela/MessOverride is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 * 
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 * 
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

namespace Gabriela\MessOverride\Plugin\Magento\Framework\Message;

class AfterCollection extends Magento\Framework\Message\Collection

public function getMessages($clear=false)
{
    if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'WORDPRESS_PATH')) {
        return $_objectManager->get("core/message_collection");
    }
    if (!$this->getData('messages')) {
        $this->setMessages($_objectManager->get('core/message_collection'));
    }

    if ($clear) {
        $messages = clone $this->getData('messages');
        $this->getData('messages')->clear();
        $manager->dispatch('core_session_abstract_clear_messages');
        return $messages;
    }
    return $this->getData('messages');
}
```

I'm not sure I'm following the right path. I'm wondering if the best aprroach is to create a plugin. And I don't know if my code is totally right. I'm also wondering why my Magento 2 question was labeled as off-topic in the Magento 2 forum.

Comment: You are using Magento2 right ?  If so, the usage of Mage::getModel("core/message_collection");  is not supported in Magento2. Make sure the class you are using is compatible with Magento-2. Most probably, right now, you are using an out-dated version of Magento1 code in a Magento-2 environment.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure I'm following the right path.

Probably not. I'll explain below as far as I can based on what you showed.

> And I don't know if my code is totally right

The code in `getMessages()` is Magento 1 code (apparent by the use of `Mage::`). I don't know what you are trying to achieve there, but this will not work at all in Magento 2.

> The message suggests that I should provide a autoload function to Manager.php

This is just a symptom. If you fix it, another one will pop up. The root problem is that your Wordpress/Magento integration tries to serialize Magento objects, which is a very bad idea from several perspectives (performance, security, stability). **How to fix that problem?** I have no idea, because I don't know the integration.

And this brings us to:

> I'm also wondering why my Magento 2 question was labeled as off-topic in the Magento 2 forum

Questions that need internal knowledge of third party extensions are likely to get closed here, especially if their source code is not publicly available.

Comment: Continuing the last part of my answer in the comments because it gets too chatty. You might have more luck in the actual **Magento Forum** at https://community.magento.com/ As you might have noticed, StackExchange works differently than a forum. It's just Q&A: Questions that have a true answer. If anything needs back-and-forth-discussion, it's not considered a good question. The neutral objective tone might sound unfriendly but that's not the intention, it's just a nerd site ;-) Please feel welcomed anyways!

Comment: I edited the code to remove M1 lines. But I didn't and I will not test the code. I found another solution that is not related to Magento. I dropped the bad plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank Nisse Engström for the elegant edition. 
I probably added some M1 code M2, my mistake. I found a solution for a very similar problem but for a integration Wordpress/M1 from Cadence Labs. It is a very popular plugin for Wordpress that suggest this workaround in M1 install to get everything working. 
My problem just happens when I enable one of wordpress plugins at Worpress install. If it is not enabled, my integration works like a charm. The integration mainly happen in Wordpress site, so I installed a plugin that gets Magento 2 header and footer and some of blocks like products by category and sku. That's why I didn't post the wordpress code in a magento fórum. I just added Magento 2 code. But the most weird of all is that the error pops on Magento 2 code but it doesn't prevent the root Magento site to load correctly. Everything works except this plugin. Anyway, thanks for your attention. I will dig a little further.